# How to set a function from an external python library as custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I recently started working with python and more specifically with Keras for a machine learning application.

I want to train an artificial neural network with the following custom loss function that makes use of the [hypervolume](http://esa.github.io/pygmo/documentation/hypervolume.html), given in the pygmo library:

```
def hypervolume_difference_loss(y_true, y_pred):  

    import numpy as np
    from pygmo import hypervolume

    ref_point = [1.0, 1.0]
    ref_PF = np.array(y_true) 
    out_PF = np.array(y_pred)  

    hv_d = np.empty(shape=y_true.shape[0], dtype=float)

    for i, (ref_point _i, out_PF _i) in enumerate(zip(ref_point , out_PF )):
        ref_hv_obj = hypervolume(points=ref_point .reshape(10, -1,order='F'))  
        out_hv_obj = hypervolume(points=ref_point .reshape(10, -1,order='F'))  
        ref_hv = ref_hv_obj.compute(ref_point )
        out_hv = out_hv_obj.compute(ref_point )
        hv_d[i] = abs(ref_hv - out_hv)

    return hv_d
```

Based on Keras documentation the custom loss function has to be a tensorflow symbolic function. I have found several examples (e.g. [link](http://www.riptutorial.com/keras/example/32022/euclidean-distance-loss)) showing how to write such a symbolic function with the use of  Keras backend functions but I was not able to find a way to write a symbolic function that can use the result of an external library.

I recently found a similar issue in this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6652) but no solution is provided. The only workaround I can think of is to re-write the hypervolume function with Keras backend representation. Could you please let me know if there is any more convenient way?

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help or recommendation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you and the following implementation should work for you. I got this implementation from [GitHub](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2121#issuecomment-214551349), where closure technique is used to involve loss function.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.convolutional import *

def penalized_loss(noise):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true) - K.square(y_true - noise), axis=-1)
    return loss

batch_size=32
timesteps=6
features=8

input1 = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, features))
lstm =  keras.layers.LSTM(features, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(input1)
output1 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(features, activation='sigmoid'))(lstm)
output2 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(features, activation='sigmoid'))(lstm)
model = Model(input=[input1], output=[output1, output2])
model.compile(loss=[penalized_loss(noise=output2), penalized_loss(noise=output1)], optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Are you aware of any good tutorial on the use of Lambda layer to implement custom loss function? The process that I have been following was to add the necessary input, hidden and output layers to my sequential model and then compile it with the appropriate loss function and optimizer. In my understanding the Lambda layer should be set as the final layer (after the output layer). Is that right? And what happens if the custom loss function needs both the y_pred and y_true?

Comment: The code in your comment gives an example on how to add more input parameters to the loss function than just the y_true and y_pred by using a separate function that returns another function. However, the custom function that I want to use has just two input parameters (as shown in my edited question). So in that sense I am covered with the use of one function which represents the loss function. My question is mainly on the part of how to use Keras backend to write a custom loss function that involves the use of external libraries (in my case hypervolume). Thank you for your time.